# How to solve this nonlinear vector equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\gamma > 0$. Now I would like to find a solution for $\alpha$ of the following equation,

\begin{align}
Z - \alpha = \gamma\frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|_{2}} .
\end{align}

I am totally unfamiliar with such an equation. So I already get stuck here. Any help is really appreciated (or sources/references).

Thanks,

p.s apologies for the limited (just one) tags. I was not sure which tags would be appropriate.

Comment: A necessary condition is that $Z$ must be a multiple of $\alpha$...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for your comment. I find it a bit counter intuitive to talk about Z must be... Since I am looking for a $\alpha = ...$. However, I understand that $\alpha$ must be a multiple of $Z$ is a equivalent argument. Is this meant as hint? Maybe a little more on how I would find the factor?

Comment: Hint: $Z - \alpha = \gamma\frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|}
\iff Z = \left(1+\frac{\gamma}{\|\alpha\|}\right)\alpha
\implies \|Z\| = \|\alpha\| + \gamma$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Z - \alpha = \gamma\frac{\alpha}{\|\alpha\|_{2}}  \Longleftrightarrow Z = \alpha \left( 1 + \gamma\frac{1}{\|\alpha\|_2}\right) \quad \quad (*)$$

Taking the $||.||_2$, you get that $$||Z||_2 = ||\alpha||_2 \left( 1 + \gamma\frac{1}{\|\alpha\|_2}\right) = ||\alpha||_2 + \gamma $$

so you must have $||\alpha||_2=||Z||_2-\gamma$. So if $||Z||_2 \leq \gamma$, the equation has no solution. If $||Z||_2 > \gamma$, then $(*)$ gives
$$Z = \alpha \left( 1 + \gamma\frac{1}{||Z||_2-\gamma}\right), \quad \text{so} \quad \alpha = \frac{1}{\left( 1 + \gamma\frac{1}{||Z||_2-\gamma}\right)}Z =\frac{||Z||_2-\gamma}{||Z||_2}Z $$

(if $Z \neq 0$) and you can check that this is indeed a solution.

Comment: Thank you very much ( to you all ). Kind of embarrassed, I just forgot that you can take the constant outside the L2-norm.

Answer (score 0):

let $\mathbb{R}^n=\alpha\mathbb{R}\bigoplus\left(\alpha\mathbb{R}\right)^{\perp} $

You have : $Z=z_{\alpha}u_{\alpha}+z_{\perp}u_{\perp} $ and $\alpha=\alpha u_{\alpha} $

So you get $z_{\perp}=0 $ and :
$$z_{\alpha}=\alpha+\gamma \\\alpha=\left(|| Z||-\gamma\right)\frac{Z}{||Z||} $$

(which is also equivalent to the result of the other answer)